# Understanding RegEx that finds multiline HTML comments

Tags: c#, javascript, html, .net, regex

I have a RegEx found here http://regexadvice.com/forums/thread/36397.aspx and I am looking for an explanation of a behavior that I don't understand.  The RegEx is supposed to find multi-line HTML comments that are NOT inside script or style tags.  I'm using it to build an app that can strip browser accessible comments post-build. For example, find this

```
<!-- I am an ordinary comment
and I need two lines -->
```

but not this

```
<script language="javascript1.2">
<!--
function window_Onload()
{   
    alert('I am the on load event');
}
window.onload=window_Onload;
//-->
</script>
```

Once found, I can remove the first comment chunk while ignoring the second.

The following pattern works absolutely beautifully to accomplish the above:

```
string multilinePattern = @"<!--((?!-->).)+-->(?>((?!</?(script|style)).)*)(?!</(script|style))";
match = Regex.Match(text, multilinePattern);
                    if (match.Success)
                    {
                        output.WriteLine("{0}", match.Value);
                    }
```

This code will give me a file with all of the html comments NOT inside a script or style tag, but it does something else I don't get.

Here's ***Example 1*** of HTML and the return:

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Outside Table -->
<table summary="<%= GetLocalResourceObject("LayoutTable.SummaryText") %>" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td class="tableHeader">&nbsp;</td>
```

Returns:

```
<!-- Outside Table -->
```

Now, here's ***Example 2*** of HTML and the return:

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Outside Table -->

<table  summary="<%= GetLocalResourceObject("LayoutTable.SummaryText") %>" class="tabTableCell"   cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="750" align="center" >

    <tr>

        <td class="tableHeader">&nbsp;</td>
```

Returns:

```
<!-- Outside Table -->

<table  summary="<%= GetLocalResourceObject("LayoutTable.SummaryText") %>" class="tabTableCell"   cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="750" align="center" >

    <tr>
```

Example 2 is the wrong one: I don't want to include that chunk of html in the match result.  But the only difference I can see between Examples 1 and 2 is the extra line break that follows the "Outside Table" notation in Example 2.

So my question is, what is it in the Regex that's causing the match to include the html all the way up to the TR tag in example 2.  What would I have to change to get the Regex to match Example 2 the same way as example 1?

Comment: This returns the correct result for me. Also: You really shouldn't be using Regex for parsing HTML. The fact you're asking this question and having issues matching markup is the exact reason you shouldn't be doing it.

Comment: There are dozens of questions about regex and HTML, all of them say, DONT DO IT! Use HTMLAgilityPack instead.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, there are ways of flagging a comment you may think is unconstructive rather than resorting to ad hominem attacks.  I was trying to be helpful, I think HTML Agility Pack is the way to go here.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Does the very fact this question exists not support paqo's comment? The OP is having trouble matching EXTREMELY SIMILAR markup with a single regular expression. That is **the entire argument against using Regex for HTML**.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: So, are you saying that issue is a result of hitting the tree structure with `(script|style)`? Because I was viewing it as just scanning text, albeit text with lots of special characters.

@paqogomez: I almost discarded this when I saw remarks re: HTMLAgilityPack, but I'm not sure that precisely what I'm doing is what that pack is for.  I'm not parsing to get data off the page, I'm scanning text to remove anything between `<!--` and `-->`.  To me that's not parsing.

Comment: That is still "parsing". Honestly, if you're removing comments.. it is trivial with HTML Agility Pack.. and it is exactly what that library is for.

Comment: @paqogomez: It isn't an ad homininem attacks, sorry if you think that. HTML Agility Pack can be usefull sure, however I am tired of people that are unable to resolve a problem with a simple pattern (always lighter than using a library and the full load of an html tree) and are hidden behind supposed "the cleanest way". However your opinions and comments are always welcome.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Thanks, the explanation is appreciated (although I'm still curious WHY the regex doesn't work in this case, for my own edification).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, I agree, people that dont think, dont contribute to the conversation.  Please feel free to share *your* answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my tests it matches just the comment in both cases.  But if I specify the `Singleline` option (which you should be doing), it matches the whole shebang in both cases.  Could it be that you're doing the match in `Singleline` mode in your second test, but not the first?

But that's a bad regex anyway.  After the comment is matched, the atomic group matches *and consumes* anything that's not a SCRIPT or STYLE tag (opening or closing), and then the lookahead asserts that what follows is not a closing SCRIPT or STYLE tag.

You don't want to consume anything after the end of the comment; that should all be in one negative lookahead.  For example:

```
(?inxs)
<!--((?!-->).)+-->
(?!
  ((?!</?(script|style)).)*
  </(script|style)
)
```

`(?inxs)` is an inline mode modifier; it switches on `IgnoreCase`, `ExplicitCapture`, `IgnorePatternWhitespace`, and `Singleline` modes.  Here it is again, all in one line as a C# verbatim string:

```
@"(?ins)<!--((?!-->).)+-->(?!((?!</?(script|style)).)*</(script|style))"
```

Comment: While I'll probably try out HTML Agility Pack (I just don't have enough time to learn Regex for this project) this expression worked perfectly. And I appreciate the explanation for WHY it worked and the other didn't.

Comment: Also, forgot to mention, I am not using `SingleLine` mode in the second test and not the first.  Both tests result from a single run of an app that iterates all text in all files and reports back on the matches it finds.  So if one test was using `SingleLine` mode, the other was as well.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

OK here is how it could be done with HtmlAgilityPack

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var comments = doc.DocumentNode
                .Descendants()
                .Where(d => d.Name == "#comment")
                .Select(d => d.InnerText)
                .ToList();
```